# In which event-phase can a super-class refer to a potential existing component in it's derived-class?

Tags: apache-flex, reference, mxml, derived-class, superclass

In Flex, lets say I have a super-class... something like:

```
class SuperComponent extends DragStack {

   private var _childReference:UIComponent;

   public function SuperComponent() {
      // ???
      addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationComplete);
   }

   private function onCreationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void {
      //The 'this[]' technique doesn't seem to work and causes run-time errors:
      //trace("Component found: " + this["myButton"]);
   }
}
```

And then I make use of the following derived-class in my application (just a mockup MXML as an example):

```
<!-- Component ChildComponent.mxml -->
<mx:SuperComponent>
  <mx:Button id="myButton" label="Press Me!" />
</mx:SuperComponent>
```

How do I go about verifying the presence of "myButton" from the SuperComponent class, and referencing it? Do I need to use getChildByName( ... ) ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what type of component DragStack is.  Does it extend Container (Flex 3) or Group (Flex4)?  If so, then the component will go through it's [lifecycle process](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ascomponents_advanced_2.html), and myButton should be accessible after createChildren method is executed.

I believe that MXML does some magic under the hood to create the button as a child of your component.

If DragStack is not a container, then you have to tell us what the default property of DragStack is.  The DefaultProperty would be specified in [class metadata](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/metadata_3.html#166318).

I believe what the MXML does is, basically, assign the XML Children to the default property of the  SuperComponent class if no other property is specified.  If you want to assign it to a different property, you'll have to specify it, like this:

```
<mx:SuperComponent>
  <mx:myProperty>
  <mx:Button id="myButton" label="Press Me!" />
 </mx:myProperty>
</mx:SuperComponent>
```

This syntax is usually only used in situations where the property doesn't have a simple value, such as the array of columns for a DataGrid.

Comment: Hi @www.Flextras.com, DragStack extends ViewStack, which extends Container.

Comment: @bigp Then I believe the first part of my answer is what you're after.  You should be able to access the button instance after createChildren is run.  The caveat is that I thought a ViewStack's children had to be containers, which a Button is not.  And that ViewStack's children were created conditionally--as needed--based on the ViewStack's creationPolicy.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this["myButton"]` from within containers even if `myButton` is a child of that container added in MXML. `myButton` is still not a class property but element of container's children.

You'd better [use `getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Container.html#getChildByName%28%29) passing `"myButton"` as a name.